# Monitoring Power/Connection status with INA219 and Arduino

Tags: usb, i2c, usb-c, usb-pd, ina219

Hey all I am looking to monitor the voltage/plugged in of a USB-C device.

I am using the [INA219](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina219.pdf?ts=1708195449525&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.de%252F) to monitor the voltage using the I2C (SDA/SCL) lines to my Arduino (not shown in the schematic).

I just want someone who's more knowledgeable about USB-C PD to let me know if what I have here will work with checking when the item is plugged in.

The R1 is a [RESC6331X70N](https://www.koaspeer.com/pdfs/RK73B.pdf).

I based the INA219 off of this from Adafruit.

[image]

[image]

This is what I am trying to do - a led that is there to indicate when the power source is connected to a device.

[image]

Comment: It depends what device you want to monitor and with which cable. The VConn may not be used by a cable or device at all, and a source may not provide it if there is no cable that requests it.

Comment: The question contains ``monitor the voltage/plugged in of a USB-C device``, but the schematic shows the INA219 connected to monitor the voltage/current from the ``VCONN`` pin rather than the ``VBUS`` pin of the USB-C plug. From [USB Type-C VCONN Requirements](https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/USB-Type-C-VCONN-Requirements) VCONN is only to supply an e-marker or USB3/USB4/Alternate Mode signal redriver ASIC embedded within the USB Type-C _cable_. Whereas ``VBUS`` supplies power to the actual USB-C _device_. Can the question be edited to clarify which is to be monitored?

Comment: @ChesterGillon if the VBUS is used when connecting the device then that would be the one I’m looking to check. I just didn’t know which one it would be so that if one side is plugged into a power source then it wouldn’t indicate it was connected to the device until the other said was actually connected as well.

Comment: @StealthRT The USB standards are open and freely available for download. Required reading for you: https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-cr-system-overview https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-cr-cable-and-connector-specification-release-23